# Specific Loop For 2 <div> Within Each <li>

Tags: php, loop, query, count, offsets

I need to create a loop that can logically be described as the following for a carousel:
Requirements:

- 3 Loops
- 2 Posts Per Loop
- No Duplicates
- Order by Post Date

Visual:

```
< Start Loop #1 >
< Post #1 >
< Post #2 >
< End Loop #1 >

< Start Loop #2 >
< Post #3 >
< Post #4 >
< End Loop #2 >

< Start Loop #3 >
< Post #5 >
< Post #6 >
< End Loop #3 >
```

Ideally, I would like a solution that could carry on infinite loops this way with no duplicates. I looked in the WP codex, but I could not find a specific solution that fit with my code shown here: http://pastebin.com/LitYb0wh

How can I make the loop to work with this type of structure?

```
<ul>

<li>
<div>Post 1</div>
<div>Post 2</div>
</li>

<li>
<div>Post 3</div>
<div>Post 4</div>
</li>

<li>
<div>Post 5</div>
<div>Post 6</div>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: is there a reason it needs to be separate queries? can you not query for all the posts you want in one query and handle it via a single loop?

Comment: V, you can post all the necessary code inside your Question, but try to remove non-relevant parts for easier reading/understanding.

Answer (score 1):

i use this code in my portfolio http://pocketapps.co/

[image]

```
<?php $args = array(
                                    //your argument code
                                );
            query_posts($args);?>

            <ul>
                 <?php  
                 $ls=0;
                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            ?>
                    <?php if($ls%2==0): echo '</li><li>'; endif; ?>
                    <div class="app">
                            //your code here

                    </div>
             <?php 
                $ls++;
                endwhile;
                wp_reset_query();
             ?>
            </ul>
```

Comment: -1 for using `query_posts`

Answer (score 0):

To precisely match your three `<ul>` pattern you can do this:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query();
$my_query->query($args);
$skip = 2;
echo '<ul>';
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
  $my_query->the_post();
  echo '<li>'.$post->post_title.'</li>';
  if ( ( ($my_query->current_post-1) % $skip ) == 0) {
    break;
  }
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '<ul>';
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
  $my_query->the_post();
  echo '<li>'.$post->post_title.'</li>';
  if ( ( ($my_query->current_post-1) % $skip ) == 0) {
    break;
  }
}
echo '</ul>';
echo '<ul>';
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
  $my_query->the_post();
  echo '<li>'.$post->post_title.'</li>';
  if ( ( ($my_query->current_post-1) % $skip ) == 0) {
    break;
  }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

However, the following it smaller, neater, and should create any number of `<ul>`s depending on the size of the query, which I assume is what you mean when you say "infinite loops this way".

```
$my_query = new WP_Query();
$my_query->query($args);
$skip = 2;
while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
  if ( ( ($my_query->current_post-1) % $skip ) == 0) {
    echo '<ul>';
  }
  $my_query->the_post();
  echo '<li>'.$post->post_title.'</li>';
  if ( ( ($my_query->current_post-1) % $skip ) == 0) {
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}
```

An option using a single `<ul>`

```
$my_query = new WP_Query();
$my_query->query($args);
$skip = 2;
echo '<ul>';
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    if ( ( ($my_query->current_post-1) % $skip ) == 0) {
      echo '<li>';
    }
    $my_query->the_post();
    echo '<div>'.$post->post_title.'</div>';
    if ( ( ($my_query->current_post-1) % $skip ) == 0) {
      echo '</li>';
    }
  }
echo '</ul>';
```

The `$args` I used to test is...

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 8,
  'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

... but this should work with any that your provide.

It does assume that you don't want to query for a distinct set of posts for each Loop.

Obviously, I did not work this into your existing code but the pattern should be easy to apply.

Comment: Elegant approach.

Comment: Guys, 

Thank you so much for the input! I should have clarified more in that I need infinite <li></li> within one <ul></ul> grouping.

I am assuming the solution would work the same way? I am working on the code now and I will post up as soon as I finish.

Comment: Ok,

I updated the latest code, which unfortunately, still isn't working: [link](http://pastebin.com/LitYb0wh)

So, the carousel is basically 1 <ul> with quite a few stuffs in between the </ul>.

The basic loop would allow the following: 

`<ul>

<li>
<div>Post 1</div>
<div>Post 2</div>
</li>

<li>
<div>Post 3</div>
<div>Post 4</div>
</li>

<li>
<div>Post 5</div>
<div>Post 6</div>
</li>

</ul>`


Where the carousel container is the <ul> and 2 post thumbs and their titles are displayed side-by-side per "slide".

You can see an example here: http://video.gq.com/

2nd carousel down. 

Thanks!

Comment: There is no significant difference. Just put the `<ul>` outside the loop and use `<li>` inside it.

Comment: While loop constructs and loop HTML/CSS markup are not **WordPress** specific, and your comment really starts to approach *work for me for free* territory.