# Output 2 items within the Loop

Tags: php, loop, conditional-tags, the-content

I have a query that loops through `<li>`'s and displays the number of `<li>`'s I have.  Is there a way I can make the loop pull 2 `<li>`'s at a time rather than one?

```
// 5 list items
<ul>
<?php while(has_posts()): the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <div class="slide"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

output

```
<ul>
    <li><div class="slide">content 1</div></li>
    <li><div class="slide">content 2</div></li>
    <li><div class="slide">content 3</div></li>
    <li><div class="slide">content 4</div></li>
    <li><div class="slide">content 5</div></li>
</ul>
```

and how I would like it to output...

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <div class="slide">
           content 1
           content 2
       </div>
   </li>
   etc...
</ul>
```

I hope you understand what I am trying to do.

Thanks!

Comment: You could find the [info you need](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+counter+every+2) via google.... (poor search terms, but the basic principle of what you need is still there, determine when X is multple of Y and do Z)..

Comment: This is effectively the same question as here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96943/specific-loop-for-2-div-within-each-li/96946#96946 I provided what I believe to be a very effective generic solution for this kind of Loop structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy using [WP query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) (get to know it...)

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $recentPosts = new WP_Query();
        $recentPosts->query('showposts=2'); // SET AMOUNT HERE
    ?>
    <?php while ($recentPosts->have_posts()) : $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
        <li><div class="slide"><?php the_content(); ?></div></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you encounter any issuse.

---

**EDIT 1:**
* explenation - just added a small conditional counter

```
<ul>
    <?php 
        $count = 1;
        while(has_posts()): the_post(); 
    ?>

        <?php if ($count == 1) {echo '<li><div class="slide">';} ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php if ($count == 3) {echo '</div></li>'; $count = 1;} else {$count++;} ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
* please note i changed has_post to have_post (think it should be that way? your call)

```
<?php 
    echo '<ul>';
    $count = 1;

    while(have_posts()): the_post(); 

    if ($count == 1) {$slideOpenTag = '<li><div class="slide">';} else {$slideOpenTag = '';}
    if ($slideOpenTag) {echo $slideOpenTag;}

    the_content();

    if ($count == 3) {$slideCloseTag = '</div></li>'; $count = 1;} else {$count++; $slideCloseTag = '';}
    if ($slideCloseTag) {echo $slideCloseTag;}

    endwhile;
    if (!$slideCloseTag) {echo '</div></li>';}
    echo '<ul>';        
?>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't want to display JUST 2 items, I want the loop to display 2 items at a time in the same div. Make sense?

Comment: sure, revising... 2 minutes :)

Comment: do I need to increment the count? e.g. ++$count;

Comment: wow... left my head somewhere - fixed it (your right of course.)

Comment: also good to note that this is a fast readble solution. while writing this i wish i had a place to test small stuff like that so i could offer a complete answer... so i think this inspired me and would create a local installation for small testings like that ;)

Comment: Yep, it's nice to have @Sagive SEO, try running it with toscho's stripped down _s theme: https://github.com/toscho/Toscho-s-Mini-Theme

Comment: Seems like it's what I'm looking for, in the middle of something else at the moment, but will give it a go and accept when it works! :)

Comment: the devil is as always in the detail - you need to provide a closing tag solution for uneven numbers of posts.

Comment: your right (hehe the devil indeed)...  going to have to give it some tought but will add an edit soon

Comment: Ok... i think i got it! Aint the most beautiful code but works (tested!)

Answer (score 3):

Drawing on [Sagive SEO](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/7990/sagive-seo)'s post this also seems to work without using counters.

```
echo '<ul>';

while ( have_posts() ) {
    echo '<li><div class="slide">';

    the_post();
    the_content();

    // If there is 1 more post, advance current post and add its content.
    if ( $wp_query->current_post + 1 < $wp_query->post_count ) {
        the_post();
        the_content();
    }

    echo '</div></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

The WordPress function [the_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post) advances the $wp_query object post index, just like the next_post() [WP_Query object](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) method does. Adding a second call to the_post() affects the value of the have_posts() function.

This loop process two posts per loop instead of one unless an odd number of posts are returned in which case the conditional will be false and only the last post will be processed on the last loop pass.

EDIT:
Some Math for 7 total posts.

$wp_query->post_count = 7

$wp_query->current_post The index of the post currently being displayed (starting with 0).

Pass one. The first `the_post()` initializes `$wp_query->current_post` to 0. if ( 0 + 1 < 7 ). The conditional `the_post()` increments `$wp_query->current_post` to 1.

Pass two. The first `the_post()` increments `$wp_query->current_post` to 2. if ( 2 + 1 < 7 ). The conditional `the_post()` increments `$wp_query->current_post` to 3.

Pass three. The first `the_post()` increments `$wp_query->current_post` to 4. if ( 4 + 1 < 7 ). The conditional `the_post()` increments `$wp_query->current_post` to 5.

Pass four. The first `the_post()` increments `$wp_query->current_post` to 6. if ( 6 + 1 < 7 ). The conditional is false and does not execute.

Comment: Very nice - much cleaner - but - doesnt work ;( (tested it) - do the math (7 posts === (cur=1+1)<7 RESULT=run) ELSE (7 posts === (cur=2+1)<7 RESULT=run) - Runs every time unless 1 before last.  Am i missing something?

Comment: I worked for me using 3 posts. If you use it from a function you need to make `$wp_query` global. See the edit above for the math.

Comment: yee but he wanted this>>  [box] {content}{content}{content} [/box] & again... NM mate - just that using the $wp_query->post_count along with not extra calculation wont do but its a great approach -> maybe somthing like >>  if ( ($wp_query->current_post + 1)  % 3 == 0) is the right way

Comment: Romes says he wants <div>{content}{content}</div>. Two contents, not three. Each pass of the loop advances the post index twice. Once for each post.

If an odd number of posts are returned in the query then the last pass of the loop will attempt to grab a post which doesn't exist. The conditional prevents that.